# SSH2 fails authentication with a working key converted with PuttyGen (due to deprecated ssh-rsa?)

Tags: ssh, authentication, ssh-keys

I have an EC2 instance authenticated with a key-pair generated by AWS.

With Putty, I can connect to the instance by providing the private key in a PPK file.

When I try to use SSH2 (via one of the NodeJs wrappers, e.g. through the 'ssh2-sftp-client' module), it fails with an error:

`getConnection: All configured authentication methods failed`

And the auth.log on the instance reports,

`sshd[1841]: userauth_pubkey: key type ssh-rsa not in PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms [preauth]`

I know that OpenSSH has deprecated ssh-rsa but I am still not sure what is wrong here:

- ssh-rsa seems to mean a number of things, and it appears only SHA1 has been deprecated. My key is SHA256 as reported by PuttyGen however so should still work, no?
- If I understand right, changing from ppk to pem just changes the layout and encoding of the file, not the key value itself. If the OpenSSH *server* is the one doing the rejection, why does Putty work OK?

**Does converting from PPK to PEM change the type of the key? If so, how can I convert PPK to PEM into something other than ssh-rsa?**

The SSH (server) version is `OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022`

-- Edit because I can't comment yet --

@Tanjin Alam's answer is correct, and in AWS this can be done automatically when the machine is built by adding the following text to the `User Data` field in the launch template:

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -i '$aPubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-rsa' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
service sshd restart
```

Comment: Add output of **ssh -fNvv user@host |& grep "debug.*host key algorithms"** to check what algorithms supported by server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Goto

```
/etc/ssh #goto this directory
sudo nano sshd_config #edit the file
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-rsa #add this line and save and quit 
sudo systemctl restart sshd #restart sshd
```

Try again it will work

Reference : [Click HERE](https://github.com/liximomo/vscode-sftp/issues/37)

Comment: Be aware that by doing this, you are allowing sha1 RSA authentication, which is considered weak.